# How to get repeat function play sound more than once in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have some difficulty with making script below to work as intended, which is to play sound repeatedly as in the function (repeatR). Input for the number of repetitions may come from user (button).

```js
    var timer, start;
    
    function repeatR(callback, interval, repeats, immediate) {
        var timer, trigger;
        trigger = function() {
            callback();
            --repeats || clearInterval(timer);
        };
    
        interval = interval <= 0 ? 1000 : interval; // defaultní
        repeats = parseInt(repeats, 10) || 0; // loop
        timer = setInterval(trigger, interval);
    
        if ( !! immediate) { 
            trigger();
        }
    
        return timer;
    }
    
    window.run = function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
        if( timer ) { clearInterval(timer); }
        start = (new Date).getTime();
        document.getElementById("test").play();
    }
```

```html
    <body>
            <div>
    <input type="button" value="Once after 1 sec" onclick="run(1000, 1)">
    <input type="button" value="Once immediately" onclick="run(0, 1, true)">
    <input type="button" value="5 times, 0.5s interval" onclick="run(500, 5)">
    <input type="button" value="5 times, 0.5s interval, immediate start" onclick="run(500, 5, true)">
    <input type="button" value="Forever, 1s interval" onclick="run(1000)">
    
    
    <audio id="test" src="test.wav"</audio>
    
    
            </div>
    </body>
```

At this time code repeat the sound only once.

I would be glad for some suggestion/solutions on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you calling `repeatR` function?

Comment: You declare `timer` twice; once outside of both functions, and once inside of the `repeatR` function. Any assignment made inside `repeatR` will not affect the one outside of that function.

Comment: Remove all javascript, inside onclick for each button hardcode setTimeout(‘new function(){document.getElementById(“test”).play();}’, 500); do it as many times as you need and change timeout to 1000 for next call, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Audio loop Property which is `audioObject.loop = true|false`

```
<body> 

<audio id="myAudio" controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio><br>

<button onclick="enableLoop()" type="button">Enable loop</button>
<button onclick="disableLoop()" type="button">Disable loop</button>
<button onclick="checkLoop()" type="button">Check loop status</button>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio");

function enableLoop() { 
  x.loop = true;
  x.load();
} 

function disableLoop() { 
  x.loop = false;
  x.load();
} 

function checkLoop() { 
  alert(x.loop);
} 
</script> 

</body>
```

Like the above code, for reference [See W3 Schools Audio Loop](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_audio_loop.asp)